# How to get php session data with ajax in ionic

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session, ionic-framework

I have a simple login system in `ionic` that is operating normally. The system checks whether the user exists in the mysql database. If the user is there, it returns `1`. If not, it returns `0`. This return value is sent via json.

My problem is that I need to send user data to the next screen and in that data insert some extra information in the user registration. For example, after logging in the application takes the `latitude` and `longitude` of the user. I want to keep this latitude and longitude on their registration.

This is the `login.php`:

```
    <?php
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$mysql_host = "localhost:3306";
$mysql_database = "melleve";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM cadast WHERE email='$email' AND senha='$senha'";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);


 $res=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 $rs = mysqli_num_rows($result);


 if($rs>0)
 {

    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();

        $_SESSION['id']=$res['id'];         
        $_SESSION['nome']=$res['nome'];
        $_SESSION['email']=$res['email'];   
        $login = 1;
 }

else
{
    $login = 0;
}


echo (json_encode($login));
?>
```

This is the login controller:

```
 .controller('lg', function($scope, $state) {


$scope.logar = function(){


var formula = $('#formLogin').serialize();


$.ajax({


type : 'POST',
data : formula,
url : 'http://localhost/melleve/login.php',
success : function(data){

if(data == '' || data == 0){

alert('Login ou senha inválidos');

}


if(data == 1){

alert('Login realizado com sucesso');
//$state.go('app.atigmaps');



}


}


})


}



})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are certain to get more helpful advice if you format your code cleanly. I recommend you do that so we can easily understand what you've already done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problems are this line:

```
   if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
```

1. `session_start()` should be above any use of  `$_SESSION['anywhere']`.
2. Avoid always make vague connotations, so:

   ```
   if($_session)
   ```

   always check a variable specific session, as follows:

   ```
   if(isset($_session['here'])
   ```

   Session variables are living in scope for a certain time or until you use unset

   ```
   ($ _ session [ 'here'])
   ```

Comment: Thanks buddy Paul, problem solved, was of great help.